# Почему не работает на jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
kolvoNone[chislo].show();
```

если добавить вместо `style.display='block'` `show()`, то не работает . Почему?

Comment: нужно открыть консоль и прочитать в чем ошибка

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что `.style.display='block'` - обращение к DOM-элементу, а `show()` - вызов метода jQuery:

```
$(kolvoNone[chislo]).show();
```