# Реализация не повторяющегося рандома

Tags: javascript

Есть определенный тест, который генерируют массивы с ответами, но рандом повторяет числа.

```
function randomForTest(min,max){
var su=Math.floor((Math.random()*(max-min+1))+min);
return su; } // дальше идет тест .
```

как сделать без повторений?

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/924577/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-jquery

Comment: @Igor я понял вас )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перемешайте набор неповторяющихся чисел с самого начала:

```js
function getShuffledArray(min, max) {
  var res = [];
  for (var i = min; i <= max; i++) {
    res.push(i);
  }
  res.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());
  return res;
}

var shuffled = getShuffledArray(4, 9);
console.log(JSON.stringify(shuffled));
```